# Google cloud engine connection with Bucket socket and instance

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a bucket in Google Cloud which I have upload Angular template i.e. 
http://digitaldevnet.appspot.com

then I have VM instance IP where I have WordPress website i.e. 
http://35.200.194.201

I found different tutorials where you can connect domain to Google Cloud hosting
but I want to connect appspot link i.e. http://digitaldevnet.appspot.com to WordPress site
can be connected and once we browse it should work as VM may be offline sometime.

Any recommendation and tutorial, please let me know

Comment: Just to confirm that I understand the question, you want to use the appspot domain in a GCE instance, and redirect it to the bucket again if the instances happens to be offline?

Comment: yes, i want to use appsport domain and direct to VM instance and be online whenever user check it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set up a Load balancer in order to direct your traffic between the GCE instance and the bucket, you can find the instructions for this over [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/set-up-gce-vms).

Nevertheless, it would be a bit complicated as you would need to set up the configuration and some health checks so that the GCE instance is not accessible when it's down.

Hope you find this useful.